# How to assign integer values to characters without adding asciis in Python

Tags: python, string, integer, char, ascii

I don't know how to ask this question effectively but what I need to do is assign integer values to characters in a way that the addition of the characters does not equal the first plus the second but instead the next number in the sequence.

for example:

if I used ascii values to set a-z to 1-26 then if I had the string `ab` the sum would be 3
However, I want `ab` to be assigned `27`, `ac = 28`, `ad = 29` etc.

so `a = 1` but `az = 51`(rather than 27 if i simply did `a + z`)

I'm not sure if this would affect the solution but one of the conditions is that the letters in the string must be in alphabetical order so the string could be "`abc`" but could not be "`cat`"

Thanks!

Comment: Homework?  And are you forbidding "aa" as part of your alphabetical-order criterion?

Comment: I don't fully understand the requirements.  What should be the result for `"z"` and `"aa"`?  It seems both should give 26.  Is this correct?

Comment: its a section of a project for class, aa would be excluded. since the string must be in increasing format, the second letter must come after the first letter and so on. so z would give 26 and aa would return 0

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to compute the index in the requested way without building a list of all possible strings, but it is a bit involved to do this.  Here is an implementation of an efficient method to do this:

```py
import itertools
import string

letters = string.ascii_lowercase

def _reference(max_len=4):
    """A reference implementation of the desired index operation."""
    a = []
    for k in range(max_len + 1):
        for comb in itertools.combinations(letters, k):
            a.append("".join(comb))
    return a.index

def choose(n, k):
    """The binomial coefficient "n choose k"."""
    if k < 0:
        return 0
    result = 1
    for i in range(k):
        result *= n - i
        result //= i + 1
    return result

def index(s):
    """An efficient implementation of the index operation."""
    n = len(s)
    choices = len(letters)
    result = 0
    for i, c in enumerate(s):
        new_choices = len(letters) - letters.index(c)
        result += choose(choices, n - i) - choose(new_choices, n - i)
        choices = new_choices - 1
    for i in range(n):
        result += choose(len(letters), i)
    return result

test_strings =[
    "a", "j", "ab", "az", "jw", "yz", "abc", "abhors", "almost",
    "begins", "bijoux", "biopsy", "chimps", "chinos", "chintz"]
ref_index = _reference(max(map(len, test_strings)))
for s in test_strings:
    print "{0:8}{1:8}{2:8}".format(s, index(s), ref_index(s))
```

This script compares the output of the efficient function with a brute force implementation, and the output is

```
a              1       1
j             10      10
ab            27      27
az            51      51
jw           228     228
yz           351     351
abc          352     352
abhors     91047   91047
almost    133902  133902
begins    154337  154337
bijoux    171130  171130
biopsy    172655  172655
chimps    201678  201678
chinos    201734  201734
chintz    201781  201781
```

Comment: I was **just** about to hit submit (on a code-free tutorial-like answer).  As proof my code works, indexify(''.join(sorted("misery"))) == 252666.. I used Greg K's unchoose function.

Comment: @DSM: A tutorial-like answer might be appreciated anyway, because my answer doesn't explain how it works.  I don't know anything about "unchoose" -- I just made the above code up from some basic combinatorial considerations.

Comment: @will: If this answers your question, you can accept the answer by clicking the check mark on the left.